# php trying to save image from the web, error

Tags: php

I can't get this script to save an image to a folder... The error is:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/tmp/image2.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/testqr.php on line 15 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/testqr.php on line 16 
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/testqr.php on line 17
```

Comment: It's likely that the user running your web server doesn't have write permissions to the folder in question.

Comment: I set full permissions on that folder though

Comment: Can you post your code? It's hard to tell you why code we haven't seen doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/image2.png';
$file = fopen($fl, "w");
$url = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=http://superiorwebsys.com'";
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
?>
```

do this:

```
chown -R your_username /your/directory/
chmod -R 777 /your/directory/
```

Comment: your code didn't produce any errors, but it didn't save that image to the folder. any ideas?

Comment: try using a different directory, and let me know what happens

Comment: an image doesn't get saved to the tmp directory still

Comment: cool thanks so much!!! any idea on how to prevent the owner from being www-data when the image is created? cuz it locks the image from being deleted, moved, etc.